# GridView with different position

Tags: android, gridview

Lets say I have 5 items and normal gridview will show items as follows: (in a sequence order)

```
1 2 3
4 5 x
x x x
```

Now how can I make that to look like this:

```
1 x 2
x 3 x
x 4 5
```

I know I can make that with relative view and set (x,y) of it accordingly but is that possible with gridview or GridLayoutManager?

Note: x means empty item (not showing any view)

Answer (score 0):

In adapter for getItemCount()

```
return items.size()*2
```

while binding data in onBindViewHolder()

```
if(position%2==0){
        textview.setText(items.get(position/2));
    }else{
        textview.setText(" ");
    }
```

Comment: Yes. But this will creates views for empty items! (So it's not good performance wise$